# Google Line charts Customizing vAxes with string and define position

Tags: string, google-visualization

I try to implement a Line Chart with string on xAxie and vAxie. 
For vAxie I want to start to `10eme` and finish with `1er` value. Is it possible to switch these values? 
**Today :**
10eme
9eme
8eme
7eme
6eme
4eme
3eme
2eme
1er
     1 journee / 2 journee / 3 journee / ...

**Target :**
1er
 
2eme
3eme
4eme
5eme
6eme
7eme
8eme
9eme
10eme
     1 journee / 2 journee / 3 journee / ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Journee', 'Position'],
          ['1 Journee',  10],
          ['2 Journee',  7],
          ['3 Journee',  7],
          ['4 Journee',  6],
          ['5 Journee',  8],
          ['6 Journee',  9],
          ['7 Journee',  10]
   
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Evolution au classement',
          hAxis: {title: 'Journee',  titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: {title: 'Classement'},            
    vAxis: {minValue: 1},           
    vAxis: {maxValue: 10},
          viewWindowMode:'explicit',    
    vAxis: {title: 'Classement', ticks: [{v:1, f:"1er"},{v:9, f:"9eme"},{v:8, f:"8eme"},{v:7, f:"7eme"},{v:6, f:"6eme"},{v:5, f:"5eme"},{v:4, f:"4eme"},{v:3, f:"3eme"},{v:2, f:"2eme"},{v:10, f:"10eme"}]},       
    pointSize: 5,   
        };

  
        var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

it is ok I found a way to do it with direction: -1 in vaxis option. 
here the result. 
Thank you

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Journee', 'EQUIPE 1', 'EQUIPE 2'],
          ['1 Journee',  1, 3],
          ['2 Journee',  2, 5],
          ['3 Journee',  5, 4],
          ['4 Journee',  5, 3],
          ['5 Journee',  6, 5],
          ['6 Journee',  4, 6],
          ['7 Journee',  2, 7]
   
        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Evolution au classement',
    curveType: 'function',    
          hAxis: {title: 'Journee', titleTextStyle: {color: '#333'}},
    vAxis: 
   {title: 'Classement', minValue: 0, maxValue: 11, direction: -1, ticks: [{v:0, f:""},{v:1, f:"1er"},{v:9, f:"9eme"},{v:8, f:"8eme"},{v:7, f:"7eme"},{v:6, f:"6eme"},{v:5, f:"5eme"},{v:4, f:"4eme"},{v:3, f:"3eme"},{v:2, f:"2eme"},{v:10, f:"10eme"},{v:11, f:""}]},    
    pointSize: 5,       
        }; 
 
        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```